# After virus, Chrome & Internet Explorer won't connect to the internet, but Firefox works fine

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser, internet-explorer, virus

I cannot connect to the internet with Chrome or Internet Explorer. Firefox works fine.

It seems it happens when I was infected by a "Trojan Horse Generic 17.BWIK", "Trojan Horse SHeur.UHL" and "Fake_Antispyware.FAH". I have removed the threats using AVG anti-virus security. I got Firefox working, but Chrome and IE still cannot connect.

I do not want to lose Chrome History so re-setting would be my last option and uninstall and install will be out of the question. Is there a way around this? I am using XP Pro on a desktop and DSL connection.

Answer (score 9):

Internet Explorer uses your Windows [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) settings when connecting to the internet. I'm not sure about Chrome, but Firefox can use [its own settings](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options+window+-+Advanced+panel#Connection_Settings_Dialog).

So maybe some of the malware changed your proxy settings to redirect you to some specific website. If the browsers have different settings, then that might explain why one browser can connect but another cannot.

Comment: Chrome uses the system proxy settings, just like IE. Thus, any changes to the IE's proxy settings would effect Chrome as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem about a week ago...IE and Chrome not working but Firefox worked.  Open IE and Firefox and compare the connection settings.  IE was set to use a proxy server while Firefox wasn't.

My infection also altered TCPIP.sys in this folder:

C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers

The datetime stamp on TCPIP.sys had changed or otherwise I wouldn't have noticed.  You might check the datetime stamp to make sure it doesn't match the approximate time of the infection.  I copied the file from someone else and the file hadn't been modified since 2008.

You might also open the Hosts file with Notepad and make sure nothing looks suspicious.

C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

You could reset winsock to a clean state by running this command from a command prompt in XP and then rebooting:

netsh winsock reset

Comment: Note that date/time modified can be spoofed *incredibly easily*. When you extract something from a .zip, the computer creates entirely new files, then sets the date/time modified to that of the file inside the zip. ***The virus could do this too!***

Answer (score 1):

To fix this simply go to Internet explorer

Then on the Tools menu in Internet Explorer, click Internet Options, click the Connections  tab, and then click LAN Settings. Then there will be two check boxes that are checked. First uncheck the second/bottom box then the first/top box. Then Click OK. Then Both will be fixed as Chrome uses IE configs.

Answer (score 1):

Going to:

Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Connections (tab) -> LAN Settings (button)
Then UNTICK "Us Proxy Server For Your LAN"
Then in same window select "Automatically detect your settings" then hit "ok" and if need be "Apply"

Works like a charm. I've had to fix countless computers after viruses have stopped interent explorer etc. last one stopped interent explorer and safari on this person computer chaged settings after removing the virus and it worked. Firefox has it's own settings so it works if your having that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.

I downloaded [TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363) from Kaspersky which sorted it quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the threat(s) wasn't entirely removed. AVG has a very good reputation but does occasionally miss files. I've had some good experiences with [Malwarebytes](http://malwarebytes.org/) catching "uncurable" infections on friends' computers.

Also, if you absolutely had to re-install Chrome, you would be able to [Export your Favorites and then Import them](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96816) after re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other advice, check also your system using "sfc /scannow".

See these articles:

[SFC /SCANNOW Command](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
[Scannow SFC](http://www.updatexp.com/scannow-sfc.html)